# C++11: Can I create a field whose type has a deleted destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a type whose destructor has been explicitly deleted; I'd like to make an instance of that type a member of another class.

My expectation is that should be fine provided no attempt is made to delete an instance of the containing class (ie, the containing class's destructor would be invalid).

However, both clang (v3.3) and g++ (v 4.6.3) give an error when an attempt is made to instantiate the *constructor* of the parent class.

For example:

```
class DeletedDtor 
{
  public:
    DeletedDtor() {}
    ~DeletedDtor() = delete;
};

class MyClass
{
  public:
    MyClass() = default;
    ~MyClass() = delete;

  private:
    DeletedDtor a;
};

int main() {
    MyClass *p = new MyClass();
}
```

Under g++, this gives:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:19:30: error: use of deleted function ‘MyClass::MyClass()’
test.cpp:11:5: error: ‘MyClass::MyClass()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
test.cpp:11:5: error: use of deleted function ‘DeletedDtor::~DeletedDtor()’
test.cpp:5:5: error: declared here
```

Defining the MyClass constructor myself, rather than letting it take the default implementation, doesn't help either:

```
class DeletedDtor 
{
  public:
    DeletedDtor() {}
    ~DeletedDtor() = delete;
};

class MyClass
{
  public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass() = delete;

  private:
    DeletedDtor a;
};

MyClass::MyClass() : a() {}

int main() {
    MyClass *p = new MyClass();
}
```

Which gives the compilation error:

```
test2.cpp: In constructor ‘MyClass::MyClass()’:
test2.cpp:18:24: error: use of deleted function ‘DeletedDtor::~DeletedDtor()’
test2.cpp:5:5: error: declared here
```

Comment: The class names in your code and in your error message do not match. Please clarify.

Comment: apologies, faulty c&p.

Comment: Most (non-template related) rules in C++ are about what you could possibly do, not what you actually do with your types.

Comment: (You've probably noticed this yourself already) It doesn't help to explicitly delete the destructor of `MyClass` as well.

Comment: I wonder if there's a use case for a deleted destructor...

Comment: @jrok it's very useful to ensure memory leaks on type usage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some rationale for this behaviour: There's a situation where the destructor of a member object is automatically invoked outside of the containing object's destructor: in case (something in) the containing object's *constructor* throws. Before the constructor exits, the destructors of already-constructed members and base class subobjects are invoked in reverse order of construction.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not correct, constructor is defined as deleted, since destructor of member of this class is defined as deleted, however, you simply can write

```
DeletedDtor* d = new DeletedDtor();
```

and all will works fine (without delete of course), so gcc and clang are both correct.

n3376 12.1/8

> A
> defaulted default constructor for class X **is defined as deleted** if:
>
> — any direct or virtual base class or **non-static data member has a type with a destructor that is deleted**
> or inaccessible from the defaulted default constructor.

Comment: The question is about destructor, not constructor.

Comment: This answers the question as it's worded, but can you also answer the obvious follow-up: why does basically the same error occur when you try to define a `MyClass()` constructor yourself?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Situations are different.

Comment: @ForEveR, thanks, this is a good answer. But, as leftroundabout says, it doesn't fully answer the question of whether I can have a field whose destructor is deleted, since I have (what appears to be, at least) a very similar problem if I define my own constructor for MyClass.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a copy of the actual C++ standard, but the latest working draft says:

8.4.3/2 `[dcl.fct.def.delete]`

> A program that refers to a deleted function implicitly or explicitly,
>   other than to declare it, is ill-formed.
>   [...]

When an object is destructed, the destructors of any member objects are implicitly called, and even though you're not destroying any objects a default destructor, that references the destructor of its members, is still created. Based on that, the error you are getting seems correct to me.

Comment: I don't believe this is the problem. Explicitly deleting MyClass's destructor doesn't help me here. I've updated the question to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hold an instance of the class with deleted destructor. But you can hold a pointer to `DeletedDtor` in your `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
    MyClass() = default;

  private:
    DeletedDtor* a;
};
```

Comment: I could, but that doesn't answer the question.